# How can I keep the formatting of my table from changing when reloading the data in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, realm

Here's how my UITableView looks initially. It looks great, as you can see.:

[image]

When the data is reloaded, it then looks like this (not as good):

[image]

My Realm.io object looks like this:

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class Set: Object {

    dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
    dynamic var set_id = ""
    dynamic var descr = ""
    dynamic var img_sm = ""
    dynamic var img_tn = ""
    dynamic var pieces = ""
    dynamic var qty = ""
    dynamic var theme = ""
    dynamic var year = ""

    // Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

    //  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    //    return []
    //  }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I give the user an option to change the sorting of the table via an alert where they can choose a couple options:

```
func showSorting(errorTitle:String, errorMessage:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(errorTitle)", message: "\(errorMessage)", preferredStyle: .Alert) // 1
    let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sort by Set Number", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Sorting by Number")

        self.array = try! Realm().objects(Set).sorted("set_id", ascending: true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    } // 2
    alert.addAction(firstAction) // 4

    let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sort by Set Name", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Sorting by Name")
        self.array = try! Realm().objects(Set).sorted("descr", ascending: true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } // 3

    alert.addAction(secondAction) // 5

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil) // 6
}
```

Pretty simple stuff. The Realm object is pulled and sorted the desired method and then the table is reloaded. It's the reloading of the data that is messing things up.

I'm using the Subtitle style for my table view cells.

Here's how the cell is being rendered:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(30) as! UIImageView

    let Title = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UILabel

    let subTitle = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UILabel

    Title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    subTitle.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.7176, green: 0.1647, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0) /* #b72a33 */

    let object = array[indexPath.row]

    let img_url = object.img_sm
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.set_id

    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "\(img_url)") {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        getDataFromUrl(checkedUrl) { (data, response, error)  in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
                imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }

    subTitle.text = object.descr

    return cell
}
```

I hope this helps. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that's screwing it up? Thank you for your help, I greatly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remember that when the cells are reloaded, they are *reused*. Every aspect of the cell must be reset afresh; otherwise it may be left over from its previous use.
2. It looks like you're trying to do some sort of networking inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You can't do that. You *must* return the cell *right now*. If your data requires networking, return a placeholder and do the networking separately (and reload the cells when you *don't* need to do any networking).

Thus, for example, this code is wrong:

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "\(img_url)") {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    getDataFromUrl(checkedUrl) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

You must not change any aspect of the cell directly like this after the networking delay. For all you know, the cell might not even exist by then. To fetch data from the networks, fetch it into the *model* and then just reload the table.

Comment: His network call isn't blocking, so it's fine. It just makes it so that his image will appear once it finally has a chance to download. What is wrong with it is that his code needs to be able to determine if the cell was reused before the data finished downloading, because it could end up setting the wrong image on a cell.

Comment: @Gavin No it's not fine. It has nothing to do with blocking / not blocking. You must not fulfill your `cellForRow` responsibilities post-delay as he is doing.

Comment: I think this pattern is fairly common, and there's really nothing wrong with updating the cell asynchronously, you just have to be sure that the cell is still being used for the same table location first.

Comment: I agree, though, the more proper way of doing it would be having the data model fetch the image and reload the cell when its data is downloaded. So I'm not disagreeing with that being the better route. All I'm saying is, if he updated the image view asynchronously, it's perfectly safe as long as he checks that the cell hasn't been reused yet, or somehow is able to cancel the image load upon reuse of the cell.

Comment: @Gavin If the pattern is common it's wrong. Even if it "works" it's getting the cell out of sync with the model. The correct pattern is: update the _model_ asynchronously, then update the cell from the model instantly.

Comment: @matt One of my next steps is to pull the image when the set is added, then store the image locally (no more network call). Would that make a difference or would the lookup of the image in the phone's local storage have the same effect?

Comment: @matt Yes, you can argue that it's getting the model out of sync, or you could say that the only thing related to the image that's a part of the model is the url for the image. So the actual image file in this case you could say is not a part of the model. In fact the popular AFNetworking library includes a category on `UIImageView` providing a `setImageWithURL:` method, and also `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:`, which are perfectly used in the case of a `UITableViewCell`. Reuse will even cancel the previous image download when you set a new url to load.

Comment: @matt AFNetworking also handles the caching of images loaded using that method so that once an image is already downloaded, it will be set immediately on subsequent attempts to load the image. So by using this method, you get efficient asynchronous loading of images, without constant refreshing of all other metadata of a cell, and auto image caching as well so that you don't have to worry about running out of memory because your data model starts retaining all of the images, instead they're only held in a cache that can purge them when it starts getting full.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom UITableViewCell class. This will ensure the rendering is proper. See the image below of custom uitableview cell class.

[image]

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the images have an intrinsic size. Just give your 'imageView' a static width and height. Since you are not changing the size of your cells this will make all the cells look the same.

Answer (score -2):

You can create custom table cell and must be remove  following code from the cell for row at index

```
if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "\(img_url)") {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    getDataFromUrl(checkedUrl) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just repeats the content of other answers.